# How to add this check in php/mssql query?

Tags: php, sql-server

I've got this:

```
            'char_transfertime' => $data['TransferTime'],
```

Which is getting the date from mssql column: `TransferTime` for example: `2013-08-19 18:55:00` and displays it on the users profile. But if the `TransferTime` is `NULL` it will display `NULL` on website and I want it to be `N/A`

How to add something to this above, so If `NULL` = `N/A` ?

Something like this: 

                `'char_clan'     => !isset($data['IDName']) ? "N/A" : '<a href="./?page=clan&id=' . $data['Knights'] . '">' . $data['IDName'] . '</a>');`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the syntax:

```
SELECT Class, Race, Strong, Sta, Dex, Intel, Cha, Points, 
isnull(TransferTime,'N/A')TransferTime FROM USERDATA
```

Comment: So, how to add it to this one: `'char_transfertime' => $data['TransferTime'],` I dont want to break something, will be much appreciated.

Comment: if it is regarding the last query, then I'm editing my answer and you can look at it.

Comment: I want to add it here: `'char_transfertime' => $data['TransferTime'], ` so when I display it with `<%CHAR_TRANSFERTIME%>` thats my template how it handle the stuff.

Comment: No no no, It's not regarding the previous one.

Comment: `'char_transfertime' => $data['TransferTime'], isnull(TransferTime,'N/A')` It should be like that ? Because it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

It must be like this :

```
'char_transfertime' => isset ( $data['TransferTime'] ) ? $data['TransferTime'] : 'N/A',
```

Read here about the ternary operator : http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php